# Loading data in Kaggle using the R Kernel

Tags: r, kaggle

Im new to Kaggle and hoping someone who is more experienced can help.

Im attempting to run the code below in Kaggle;

dec_2020<- read_csv("..input/divvy-trip-data/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv")

I've added the biking sharing dataset "divvy-trip-data" to my notebook and I'm trying to access the csv file "202012-divvy-tripdata.csv" which is a file in that dataset.  Whenever I do this though I get the following error;

Error: '..input/divvy-trip-data/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('/kaggle/working').

How do I load the required data or change my working directory? Ive seen some responses online for the Phyton kernel but how can i successfully load in an R kernel? Thanks

Comment: [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ananta/data-import-in-r) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/getting-started-in-r-load-data-into-r). Try '../input/..' etc

Comment: @Oliver I'm assuming you mean; '/..input/../divvy-trip-data/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv.zip' or "/..input/divvy-trip-data/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv.zip" but neither method worked..

Comment: `../input/divvy-trip-data/202012-divvy-tripdata.csv`. I'm asuming it is a csv file and not a zip file.

Comment: @Oliver I just realised you shared two links. I did exactly what they said but it still doesn't work i.e. I still get the same error message and yes they are csv files. Im really at a lost as to why its giving that message. I wanted to take a screenshot and attach but im not sure how to do so on this forum.

Comment: Finally found what I was doing wrong. I had typed in " /../input.."and not "../input.."  as I had indicated above..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.